# Whats wrong in this for loop?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, for-loop

There are few scripts getting called in my main script, one of which when executed separately executes well, but when executed from the main, gives an error as below,

```
((: s<=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

s is my variable in my for loop as,

```
for((s=1;s<=$someVar;s++))
```

I'm exporting this someVar from my main script, so that this script can use that var, however its already able to get the value of that var.

Comment: Perhaps first read about how to write a loop before trying to do it based on your own wrong assumptions!?

Comment: Obviously whatever you are doing is not giving `someVar` a value in that script. How are you `exporting` it from the script ?

Comment: my main script is exporting that someVar and that too can be successfully inherited in this script as I'm able to echo it.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant you could have helped me make it clear, downvoting just boosts me up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`someVar` is not set with a value.

I'm able to reproduce it with this:

```
for((s=1;s<=$someVar;s++)); do
    :
done
```

Error output:

```
... 3: ((: s<=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
```

P.S. You're probably running Bash 3.x.

Comment: yes, its 3.2, but all I'm saying is if the same script is able to echo the same $someVar then why is it not using in the expected substitution in my loop?

Comment: @Keys It would all be clear if you show your whole code so we can examine. Most likely it's a naming error if you're sure that your variable is really set before running the loop e.g. $someVar is not named properly.

Comment: thats nearly 500 LOC, the variable is named & exported properly :(